# What common approaches do I have to scaling data imports into a DB where the table structure is defined by Django ORM?

Tags: django, database, architecture, etl, django-orm

In the current project I'm working on we have a monolith Django webapp consisting of multiple Django "apps", each with many models and DjangoORM defining the table layout for a single instance Postgres database (RDS).

On a semi-regular basis we need to do some large imports, hundreds of thousands of rows of inserts and updates, into the DB which we use the DjangoORM models in Jupyter because of ease of use. Django models make code simple and we have a lot of complex table relationships and celery tasks that are driven by write events.

Edit: We batch writes to the DB on import with bulk_create or by using transactions where it's useful to do so.

These imports have grown, and cause performance degradation or can be rate limited and take weeks, by which time data is worth a lot less - I've optimized pre-fetching and queries as much as possible, and testing is fairly tight around this. The AWS dashboard tells me the instance is running really hot during these imports, but then going back to normal after as you would expect.

At other places I've worked, there's been a separate store that all ETL stuff gets transformed into and then some reconciliation process which is either streaming or at a quiet hour. I don't understand how to achieve this cleanly when Django is in control of table structures.

How do I achieve a scenario where:

- Importing data triggers all the actions that a normal DjangoORM write would
- Importing data doesn't degrade performance or take forever to complete
- Is maintainable and easy to use

Any reading material or links on the topic would be amazing, finding it difficult to find examples of people scaling out of this stage of Django.

Comment: You can often use `.bulk_create` to insert huge amounts of data, this will normally not take weeks.

Comment: Updating my question to incorporate. That's a good point.